# RIA + LINQ to SQL Vs RIA + Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3, ria

I am going to develop a web site will have 80,000 to 100,000 views per day. there will be less insertion operation and more retrieval operation. so Performance of website is a big issue for me. I wants to work with .NET framework (4.0) and sql server 2005. (will not use silverlight).
Please tell me which will be best suitable for me:
Should i use RIA services in it.
Should i use RIA with LINQ to SQL or with Entity Framework.
Should i use WCF services in it.
should i go with MVC2 or MVC3.

please suggest best combination like: MVC3 + RIA + LINQ to SQL + JQuery

i know i have asked many questions in single question but really i need experts advice before starting my application.

Thanks.

Comment: what would you need RIA services for? it's mainly intended for use with Silverlight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should go with MVC3 (lots of new features and improvements over MVC2) with EntityFramework 4.1 (you can use Code First which is very simple and straightforward). If you need web services, I think you should use WCF (since RIA Services is really intended for use with Silverlight).

Comment: thanks for suggestion. while doing google i found that entity framework is slower then LINQ to SQL.. also one more thing should i use RAZOR?

Comment: @Rajesh: I'm not really an expert on ORMs, but if you really find Linq2Sql better, than you should use it ;) For Razor, I think you should use it. it's a more concise syntax and realy simple and fun to use :)

Comment: I think Entity Framework is a better option than Linq to SQL. It's much better supported by Microsoft and have a lot more to offer than Linq2SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest you ditch SQL and go with RavenDB.

It is a document based database built exactly for the purpose of large data retrieval. On top it integrates smoothly with LINQ.

Other than that it should be ASP.NET MVC 3 and jQuery. If it's client-side extensive application then you should also learn Backbone.js or Knockout.js to make things a lot easier and user friendly at the client-side.